# How to auto paginate depend on container height in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a working app on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trmhduc/pjvdogoo/8/).

```
$scope.pageSize = 5;
```

What I want is that when I change the div's height, **how to do the pagination base on new height (calculate the new $scope.pageSize value)**.

For example: with height = 140px, pageSize = 5;
with height = 200px, pageSize should be another number. (how to calculate this number?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pjvdogoo/9/)

Change variable `pageSize` to a function

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("dataCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    $scope.data.push("Item " + i);
  }
  $scope.currentPage = 0;
  $scope.pageSize = function(){
    /*edit here*/
    var pagesize = $scope.divHeight / 28;
    if(pagesize < 5) pagesize = 5;
    return pagesize;
  }
  $scope.divHeight = 140;
  $scope.numberOfPages = function() {
    return Math.ceil($scope.data.length / $scope.pageSize());
  }
});
```

It should now change due to divHeight changes.

Comment: Thanks. But why do you divide $scope.divHeight / 28? What is 28?

Comment: Just a random number. The point is letting divHeight decide pageSize.